# How can I create a custom dashboard for a membership website?

Tags: membership

I'm looking to build a membership site with Wordpress. I have a decent amount of experience with wordpress, but always wondered if it's possible to create a custom dashboard for logged in members?

For example, in my membership site, members will have 100 virtual points monthly. Each time that member purchases something from me, I want to deduct from their points and display how many points they have remaining on that dashboard.

I've seen a few sites with a custom page for each different account before, but have no clue how to do this.

Thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method would be to create a single page and use a [custom page template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/).

For example, make a page with slug `my-account`. Then create a template and name it `page-my-account.php`.

Then within that template, [check if the user is logged in](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in), and [load their data](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user) if they are.

```
if( is_user_logged_in() ){
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    echo 'Username: ' . $current_user->user_login . '<br />';
    echo 'User ID: ' . $current_user->ID;
} else {
    echo 'You must be logged in to view this page';
}
```